# Does specifying HTTP protocol makes a difference?

Tags: python, html, http, https, http-headers

Is there a difference between those two bs4 objects?

```
from urllib2 import urlopen, Request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

req1 = Request("https://stackoverflow.com/")  # HTTPS
html1 = urlopen(req1).read()

req2 = Request("http://stackoverflow.com/")  # HTTP
html2 = urlopen(req2).read()

bsObj1 = BeautifulSoup(html1, "html.parser")
bsObj2 = BeautifulSoup(html2, "html.parser")
```

Do you really need to specify an HTTP protocol?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my limited understanding: There isn't a practical difference in this case.

My understanding is that most websites that have https will redirect http URLs to https, as is the case here.  It's possible for a site to have an http version and an https version up simultaneously, in which case they might not redirect.  This would be bad practice, but nothing is stopping someone from doing it.

I would still explicitly use https whenever possible, just as a best practice.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, do you have an idea why comparing the two html strings returns False? if the site redirects I would have thought that those two html strings would be the same.

Comment: I checked it manually and for me the two differences were the server response time in the header and the order of some categories at the bottom of the page.  From a content perspective they were identical.

EDIT: I think it was the hot network questions that were the things out of order/possibly different.  I deleted my scratch file already though, so I can't quickly double check.

Comment: Thank you, that's probably it.

Answer (score 1):

All communication over the HTTP protocol happens using HTTP verbs GET, POST, PUT, DELETE. Specifying the protocol has two purposes:

1) **It specifies the scheme for data communication**.

A general URI is of the form:
**scheme:[//[user[:password]@]host[:port]][/path][?query][#fragment]** and common schemes are **http(s), ftp, mailto, file, data, and irc**.

2) **It specifies if the scheme supports SSL encryption**:

With http schemes, the added *'s'* in `https` ensures SSL encryption of data.

According to `urllib3` Python [docs](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#certificate-verification):

> It is highly recommended to always use SSL certificate verification.In order to enable verification you will need a set of root certificates. The easiest and most reliable method is to use the `certifi` package which provides Mozilla’s root certificate bundle:

```
pip install certifi

>>> import certifi
>>> import urllib3
>>> http = urllib3.PoolManager(
...     cert_reqs='CERT_REQUIRED',
...     ca_certs=certifi.where())
```

The **PoolManager** will automatically handle certificate verification and will raise SSLError if verification fails:

```
>>> http.request('GET', 'https://google.com')
(No exception)
>>> http.request('GET', 'https://expired.badssl.com')
urllib3.exceptions.SSLError ...
```

Comment: While none of this is false, it doesn't really pertain much to the question.

Comment: It emphasizes on using https and how ssl verification is already available in python libraries. The accepted answer also encourages using https as best practice.